# Best way to reduce a matcher

Tags: algorithm, sorting, pseudocode

I have a matcher like so:

```
type matcher struct {
    all  []int
    none []int
    any  [][]int
}
```

For an array of integers to match, it must contain all of the integers in `all`, none of the integers in `none`, and must contain at least one integer from each array of integers in `any`. I have a factory to make the construction of such a matcher easy, but once I have the factory fields I need to "flatten" the structure to make sure none of the terms are contradictory. Right now, what I have is (pseudocode):

```
all = [0, 1, 2, 3] // means all of these numbers must be present for the matcher to match
any = [[4, 5], [6, 7, 8]] // means one number from each of these groups must be present
none = [9,10] // means none of these may be present
sort(all)
sort(none)
if len(intersections(all, none)) != 0 {
    panic("All and none are contradictory!")
}

for gIndex, group in any {
    sort(group)
    for index, integer in group {
        // If all contains the integer...
        if binarySearch(all, integer) {
            swap(group[len(group)-1], group[index]) // swap the last item with the integer...
            group = group[:len(all)-1] // and truncate the group by one; most efficient way to delete an item.
        }
        // If none contains the integer...
        if binarySearch(none, integer) {
            panic("item in any is also found in none; possible contradiction")
        }
    }
    if len(group) < 1 {
        // delete group from any
    } else if len(group) == 1 {
        // put group[0] (only integer in it) into all, since it must be met
    } else {
        sort(group) // Re-sort the group
        any[gIndex] = group // Update the group
    }
}
removeDuplicates(all)
removeDuplicates(none)
sort2D(any) // Sort by their greatest member
removeDuplicates2D(any) // Go through and remove any duplicate arrays.
```

all, any, and none should now be reduced to their simplest form, so that checking if an integer array matches should be more efficient and without contradictions.

Is there a better way to do this, and am I missing anything here?

Comment: I will note the purpose of this is to reduce matchers to allow for equality comparisons between matchers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two flaws in your solution.

1. You are removing integers in `all` from the `any` groups. In fact you have to remove the whole group instead of removing an item if there is an intersection with `all`. `any` groups containing items from `all` are just redundant.

   Having overlaps with the `none` group is not necessarily a problem. These items could in fact just be removed from the `any` groups. But then you might want to throw an error when this leads to an empty `any` group. A matcher with an empty `any` group won't match anything. Anyway, don't just quietly remove empty `any` groups!
2. Something similar applies for `any` groups subsuming other `any` groups. Consider this choice of any:

   ```
   any = [[4, 5], [4, 5, 6]]
   ```

   Let's assume that `all` and `none` are empty. Then this would remain unchanged by your algorithm. However, the second group is clearly redundant. Any array containing at least one element of the first group will also match the second. 
   This means that *at least* you have to remove all `any` arrays containing a superset of others.

I'm confident that this leads to a canonical form that you can use to compare matchers. However, I may be wrong.

Comment: So your suggestion is to remove `any` groups that are subsets of other `any` groups?

Comment: No, the other way round. Remove groups that are supersets of other groups.

Comment: You could actually simplify the whole thing by getting rid of `all`. Just create `any` groups with only one element for each `all` entry. It has the same effect but your code becomes much simpler.

Comment: Would you mind helping me figure out how to apply the above model but have mutual exclusivity as a feature?

Comment: What do you mean with mutual exclusivity as a feature?

Comment: But yes, just post a link to the updated version of your code in the comments and I can help you with it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41965870/reducing-complex-filter-rules-to-a-comparable-form is an updated version of the problem.